# Android: Layout_above adview not working on List view

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I'm trying to display banner ad below list view using *android:layout_above="@+id/adView"* but not working. List view still showing behind banner ad. How can I solve this problem? How can I put list view above banner ad or banner ad below list view?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xx/xx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/emptyList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This code results like image below. As you can see *Item 8* is showing below banner ad.

[image]

Comment: bottom margin for the listview may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listView is inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`

So add this line of code to `SwipeRrfreshLayout`

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. @Anil